# Filter object array based on multiple values

Tags: javascript, json, search, filter

I have an object array that I'd like to filter down based on user input. If the user types in "Red Shirt", only the entries that contain values like

```
{color: "red", clothingType: "shirt"}
```

should return, as opposed to

```js
{color: "red", clothingType: "scarf"}
// or 
{color: "blue", clothingType: "shirt"}
```

The main thing is that I'd like this to be generic enough to re-use for other situations like looking up "John Smith" for objects like

```js
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Smith"},
```

for instance.

Is there a simple/clean way to implement this global filter without having to get into the minutia of having the user specify the color and clothingType separately, or is that unavoidable?

I'm already using a simplified version of this for the single values by retrieving the value of "data[key]" and then using "includes" to check if "red" or "shirt" exists in the object, but I'm unsure how to search multiple values in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

This generic code will work for you:

```js
const input = "John K. Smith";
const data = [
  { firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Gauss" },
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" },
  { firstName: "Elon", lastName: "Musk" },
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Kennedy" },
  { firstName: "Adam", lastName: "Smith" }
];

console.log(
  data.filter((obj) =>
    Object.values(obj).every((value) => input.includes(value))
  )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't always assume that the properties will be adjacent enough to handle joining them together as a single string. I gave those example to be brief, but to expand a bit, it could be the case that the query string is "red shirt m" or "red m shirt" where "m" is the size of the shirt, and positioning that around the object values becomes unreliable on joins if there's many values. I'm hoping there exists a way to accomplish this without more user input, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Yes this is possible. I'm editing my answer

Comment: Answer edited, check it out

Comment: You can play around with the variables `input` and `data` to see the code in action

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Sadly, the "every" conditions fail if the input only has "John" in the input or if the objects contain any other value not included in the input (age or title for example).

Comment: Sure. The code works for the question that you asked. Now you're requesting something new